# Position section and nav elements next to each other in main section

Tags: html, css

```
<main style="overflow: hidden;">
    <nav style="width: 25%;height: inherit; display: inline-block; float:left;">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li><br>
        <li><a href="archive.html">Archives</a></li><br>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    </nav>
    <section>
        <p style="padding: 10px;">hi</p>      
    </section>        
</main>
```

How can I start the section element next to the nav element?

Answer (score 0):

Add display: `inline-block;` to your `section` element:

```
<main style="overflow: hidden;">
    <nav style="width: 25%;height: inherit; display: inline-block; float:left;">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li><br>
        <li><a href="archive.html">Archives</a></li><br>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    </nav>
    <section style="display: inline-block;">
        <p style="padding: 10px;">hi</p>      
    </section>        
</main>
```